# Derivative of Squared Step Function

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta, step-function

while studying signals & systems I ended up in the following difficult situation after digging up the unit step and delta functions a lot (I wish I hadn't do so, but couldn't help :]). Here it is:

If we define the unit step function as 
$$
u(t) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  & \mbox{if } t \geq 0 \\
  0 & \mbox{if } t < 0
 \end{array}
\right.
$$ 
the following holds I presume, $u(t)^2 = u(t)$.

Then, if we dare to take the derivative of both sides, it should be $$2u(t)\delta(t)=\delta(t)$$ which is also equivalent to $2u(0)\delta(t) = 2\delta(t)$. So, the RHS and LHS are not equal. But, they were.

So, since we're dealing with generalised functions/derivatives (which I'm not very familiar with) here, I'm making some serious mistakes in the operations above, but don't really know which ones.

Comment: Please do not pretend distributions are functions unless you know what you are doing.  Otherwise you get mistakes, such as this one.  In particular, multiplication of distributions is often not defined.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

Comment: Well, I guess, square of step function is defined as stated  in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442586/heaviside-step-function-squared. Do you mean taking derivative of $u(t)^2$ as if it is multiplication of two step functions is a wrong treatment, here? And, if true, does this mean that, once we find that $u(t)^2 = u(t)$, the derivative of this is equal to that of $u(t)$?